# Not able to update rows using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I run the following code:

```
  // Loop through each store and update shopping mall ID

  protected function associateShmallToStore($stores, $shmall_id) {

    foreach($stores as $store_id) {
      $sql .= 'UPDATE my_table SET fk_shmallID = :shmall_id WHERE id = :store_id';
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':shmall_id', $shmall_id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':store_id', $store_id);
      $stmt->execute();
    }

  }
```

I get the following message:
`Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters`

I've also tried the following without success (without `$stmt->bindParam`):
`$stmt->execute( array($shmall_id, $store_id));`

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**
I've updated my code to reflect what I actually got in my source code. There should not be any typos here.

**UPDATE 2**
I tried this, but I still get the same error message.

```
  protected function associateShmallToStore($stores, $shmall_id) {
    $i = 0;

    $sql .= "UPDATE sl_store ";

    foreach($stores as $store_id) {
      $i++;
      $sql .= 'SET fk_shmallID = :shmall_id, lastUpdated = NOW() WHERE id = :store_id_'.$i.',';  
    }

    $sql = removeLastChar($sql);
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':shmall_id_'.$i, $shmall_id);

    $i = 0;
    foreach($stores as $store_id) {
      $i++;    
      $stmt->bindParam(':store_id_'.$i, $store_id);
    }

    $stmt->execute();
  }
```

This is the output of the SQL query:

```
UPDATE sl_store 
  SET fk_shmallID = :shmall_id, lastUpdated = NOW() WHERE id = :store_id_1,
  SET fk_shmallID = :shmall_id, lastUpdated = NOW() WHERE id = :store_id_2
```

**UPDATE 3**
The code I endet up using was this:

```
    foreach($stores as $store_id) {
      $sql = "UPDATE sl_store SET fk_shmallID = :shmall_id WHERE id = :store_id";
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':shmall_id', $shmall_id);
      $stmt->bindParam(':store_id', $store_id);
      $res = $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Why did you write `SET` twice in your SQL UPDATE query? See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: @Steven, that is an invalid SQL query. What you had before was correct. Just run one update for each row and remove the concatenation operator.

Comment: @Radu - Yes, I got it working now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just as the error says, you have mixed named and positional parameters:

- `:name` (named)
- `:person_id` (named)
- `?` (positional)

More than that, you have the named parameter `:person_id`, but you're binding to `:id`.

These are your parameters, I'll call them `P1`, `P2` and `P3`:

```
UPDATE my_table SET name = :name WHERE id = :person_id ?
                           ^ P1             ^ P2       ^ P3
```

And this is where you bind them:

```
  $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name); // bound to P1 (:name)
  $stmt->bindParam(':id', $person_id); // bound to nothing (no such param :id)
```

You probably want to bind the second parameter to `:person_id`, not to `:id`, and remove the last positional parameter (the question mark at the end of the query).

Also, each iteration through the `foreach` loop appends more to the query, because you're using the concatenation operator instead of the assignment operator:

```
$sql .= 'UPDATE my_table SET name = :name WHERE id = :person_id ?';
```

You probably want to remove that `.` before `=`.

For more about this, take a look at the [Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) page in the PDO manual. You will find out how to bind parameters and what the difference is between named and positional parameters.

So, to sum it up:

1. Replace the SQL line with:

   ```
   $sql = 'UPDATE my_table SET name = :name WHERE id = :person_id';
   ```
2. Replace the second `bindParam()` call with:

   ```
   $stmt->bindParam(':person_id', $person_id);
   ```

Comment: And besides that, I see a `$sql .=`, making the query invalid after the first loop.

Comment: Maybe add that preparing the same statement over and over in the foreach is not what prepared statements are for. One could simply prepare it outside of the loop and just: `$stmt->execute(array(....));` inside the loop.

Comment: @Steven, do take into account Yoshi's comment also. The idea with a compiled statement is that you compile it once, then just bind and execute. Move the lines that compile the statement above the `foreach` loop, then just bind and execute inside the loop.

Comment: @Radu - Sorry, those are typos here in an effort to "obfuscate" my real code.. I've added my real source code now.

Comment: @Steven, then your problem is the concatenation operator. Change `.=` to `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE my_table SET name = :name WHERE id = :id';
```

Comment: @Steven: Remove the `.` before the assignment operator, just like I have suggested before. Change `$sql .= ` to `$sql = `