# Update a record with PDO using parameters

Tags: php, mysql, parameters, pdo

I'm trying to update my database table with PDO, but to avoid security leaks, I'm using parameters in my query.

I'm getting this error:
`exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in D:\xampp\htdocs\logansarchive\admin\do.article.php:25 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\logansarchive\admin\do.article.php(25): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}`

Here's my code:

```
$sql = "update articles set".
    "category = :cat,".
    "articletitle = :title,".
    "articlecontent = :content".
    "where articleid = :target";

$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(":cat", $category);
$result->bindParam(":title", $title);
$result->bindParam(":content", $content);
$result->bindParam(":target", $target);
$result->execute();
```

I found this [Not able to update rows using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829324/not-able-to-update-rows-using-pdo)
which looks fairly similar to what I'm doing, but I'm not sure how to fix my code based on this as I can't see any of the problems listed there by the guy who answered that question.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What is the need of breaking up the SQL statement and closing each quote with a new line? Why not just leave the quote open from top to bottom?

Comment: @lethalMango I assume you're the one who downvoted the question? Just call that inexperience. I do the same in vb.net to make my code more readable. As far as I was aware, this was the only way to do it.

Comment: You'll see from my profile I have never down voted a question, so that isn't me. I am all for inexperienced questions - that's one of the main uses of SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

our both codes are correct but the sql statement has two little errors. if you echo your sql then you can see that you forget two whitespaces ... one in line one after set "update articles set " and the second in line 4 after :content "articlecontent = :content " ... now it should work!

Comment: $sql = "update articles set".
    "category = :cat,".
    "articletitle = :title,".
    "articlecontent = :content".
    "where articleid = :target";

This would be read as `update articles setcategory = ...,articletitle = ...,articlecontent = ...where articleid = ...` where ... is the relevant value. Added spaces and it now works

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "update articles set ". // whitespace after set
"category = :cat,".
"articletitle = :title,".
"articlecontent = :content ". // whitespace after :content
"where articleid = :target";

$result = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(":cat", $category, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->bindParam(":title", $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(":content", $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(":target", $target, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: got any explanation why that would actually work?
Would you look at that, it doesn't...

Comment: our both codes are correct but the sql statement has two little errors. if you echo your sql then you can see that you forget two whitespaces ... one in line one after set "update articles set " and the second in line 4 after :content "articlecontent = :content " ... now it should work!

Comment: Daniel, I didn't see that, thanks. If you can put that in an answer, I'll be happy to credit your for it.